# 400 Bad-Request while making call to Bing Search API using RestTemplate

Tags: java, rest, restful-authentication, resttemplate, bing-api

I keep receiving a 400 BAD request when sending a request to Bing Search API using RestTemplate. I went through Bing Docs but didn't find the reason.

Here's my code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String bingSearchText = "hello";
bingSearchText = bingSearchText.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

String accountKey="account-key";
byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);

String bingURL = new String("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27" + bingSearchText + "%27&$top=50&$format=Atom");

HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);

MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
multiValueMap.add("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);
HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(multiValueMap);
try
{
    Map loginResponseAasMap = (Map) restTemplate.exchange(bingURL, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Object.class);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any way to log the actual call that is being made? I am curious to see if perhaps your '%27' gets encoded again.

Comment: Why have not I thought of this!
@cvesters Thank You very much.